# Downsample sublists based on length of smallest sublist

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like the following, and the number and length of sublists can be variable:

```
test = [[1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2, 4, 3, 5], [5, 3, 1]]
```

I want to downsample all sublists to the length of the shortest sublist - this case 2. That means I want to randomly select 2 elements from all sublists as an output.

For a much larger list of around 100 sublists, each greater than 100000 items, what would the most efficient way be?

Comment: what is a lesser efficient way?

Comment: Does it need to be random? How "random"?

Comment: If by "downsample" you mean "truncate long lists to the length of the shortest", then look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip.  If randonmess is desired, then you'll have to devise a more clever approach.

Answer (score 3):

Using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample) like:

#### Code:

```
min_len = min(len(x) for x in data)
[random.sample(x, min_len) for x in data]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import random

data = [[1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2, 4, 3, 5], [5, 3, 1]]
min_len = min(len(x) for x in data)
print([random.sample(x, min_len) for x in data])
```

#### Results:

```
[[5, 4], [4, 2], [4, 5], [5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only the standard library:

```
import random

test = [[1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2, 4, 3, 5], [5, 3, 1]]

min_size = float("inf")

for sublist in test:
    length = len(sublist)
    if length < min_size:
        min_size = length

new_list = [random.sample(sublist, min_size) for sublist in test]

# [[5, 4], [2, 4], [5, 3], [1, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Way to do it:

```
import random
test = [[1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2, 4, 3, 5], [5, 3, 1]]
minlen = min(list(map(lambda x: len(x),test)))
print([random.sample(i,minlen) for i in test])
```

Output:

```
[[3, 5], [4, 2], [5, 3], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet one-liner using list comprehension:

```
from random import sample

[sample(l, len(min(test, key=len))) for l in test]
```